# Rails: where vs map(&:attribute)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dictionary

Let's say we have 3 users `[User name="A"], [User name="B"], [User name="C"]`

Is there a difference between (to check presence):

`if User.where(name: "A").first`

and

```
User.all.map(&:name).include? "A"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `where` only retrieves users who match the name, via SQL.

Mapping loads all the users, builds an array of their names, and checks for 'A'.

For small numbers of users the difference in *performance* will be negligible, but both memory and time will be substantially impacted after a certain point, and `where` will be *much* better. Doing the work in the DB will be a better option than naively retrieving *all* data and doing it in Ruby.

Comment: To add to this, it means your first one is possibly **much** faster. I would use `exists?` though. `User.exists?(name: "A")`